# UITableView multiple selection with custom checkmarks

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a **`UITableView`** with **`allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing`** set to **`true`**. When I turn on editing mode the cells indent a little and some checkmarks show up.

I need those checkmarks to have a custom image or make them disappear completely so I can implement my own - keeping the indentation.

How do I change the visual of the checkmarks during editing to custom images?

Comment: I think this has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716324/uitableview-edit-mode-show-custom-buttons

Comment: I've tried that @Sparky, but the accessoryView is the one shown on the right side of the cell. I mean the checkmarks shown during editing for multiple selection on the left side.